# Mobile Redirect with javascript View Full Site link

Tags: javascript, mobile

I can not get this script to work. Basically, need the site to go to the mobile url automatically, then when on the mobile site, there is a link to return to full site.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)|(Windows Phone)|(BlackBerry)/i))) {
    document.location = "http://domainame.com/mobile";
(function(a,b) {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        return; // skip redirect
    }
    if (location.search.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        document.cookie = 'fullsite=true; path=/;'
        return; // skip redirect
    } 
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://domainname.com/mobile')
```

Linking to this url: http://flagstaffchamber.com?fullsite=true

Comment: It seems the second and third _ifs_ are equal. Isn't it lacking an _else_?

Comment: Is there a reason why your first `if` statement doesn't have a closing `}`?